# CSS Margin issues on the border

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a dotted line having some space on it's left and right side. I have used the following code for it:

```
.dotted{
  border-top:2px dotted red;
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
} 

<div class="dotted"></div>
```

This strangely places white space to the left of the dotted line; but not on the right. Can anyone please explain what is wrong with above code and how can I have white space on both side of dotted line?

Comment: There is no white-space. Your element is empty. Maybe you could explain further.

Comment: This works as you've described: http://jsfiddle.net/nj273qao/ What exactly is the problem?

Comment: use [reset css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: Voting to close as there it no problem here. [This example here](http://jsbin.com/zumona/1/edit) makes it obvious that the margin is applied on the left and right :)

Comment: Yes, actually I found that I was using an addition class row in the html, which for some reason was causing the problem.   <div class="row dotted"></div>

Comment: @dep2k - OK, just leave this question as is so it can be closed. In the future please recreate the issue and provide all the relevant HTML / CSS so we can recreate the problem as well.